# Hide homepage ads in Google Adsense Auto Ads

Tags: google-adsense

I do not want Google Adsense auto ads to appear on my website's homepage. AdSense lets you create a URL group with specific rules. However, when I use the "Select URLs for your group" feature, I can't find a way to filter out the homepage without also selecting all of the subpages. So, if I filter example.com, it also filters example.com/blog. Is there a way to choose just the homepage?

Comment: Can you remove the JavaScript snippet for AdSense from the home page?

Comment: Maybe? I'm using Rails and am an amateur. The homepage uses the same layout file as some other pages, and I included the Google javascript in the layout file. Conceivably, I could create a new layout file just for the homepage and leave out the javascript there. I'm just frustrated there's not a cleaner way. FYI, the code is 
`<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
 <script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-MYCODE",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
 </script>`

Comment: Perhaps put that code in a conditional similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142056/ror-if-statement-against-current-url